# Matching multiple tables (dataframes) using ID

Tags: r

I have the following 3 tables:

| ID | H2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3254D | YUB |
| 1011A | WSX |
| 1089 | WER |
| 1043 | RFR |

| ID | Q2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1021A | QAZ |
| 1089 | EDR |
| 3254D | DFH |
| 1043 | RFV |

| ID | X2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1011A | WSX |
| 1569V | PKJ |
| 1089 | UIO |
| 3254D | BHY |

As a newbie to R,I am looking for a way to find the intersecting columns in these 3 tables using the ID column. The desired output I am looking at are the following 3 tables:

| ID | H2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1089 | WER |
| 3254D | YUB |

| ID | Q2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1089 | EDR |
| 3254D | DFH |

| ID | X2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1089 | UIO |
| 3254D | BHY |

Please also note, that I also have a situation where it can be more than 3 tables, i.e., the solution should be able to generalize to more than 3 tables. Appreciate any suggestions. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `intersect` to get the intersecting 'ID' from all the datasets .  Then, use that to `subset` the individual datasets

```
ids <- Reduce(intersect, list(df1$ID, df2$ID, df3$ID))
subdf1 <- subset(df1, ID %in% ids)
subdf2 <- subset(df2, ID %in% ids)
subdf3 <- subset(df3, ID %in% ids)
```

-output

```
subdf1
#     ID  H2
#1 3254D YUB
#3  1089 WER
subdf2
#     ID  Q2
#2  1089 EDR
#3 3254D DFH

subdf3
#     ID  X2
#3  1089 UIO
#4 3254D BHY
```

---

If there are many datasets, and the object names follow a pattern i.e. 'df' followed by some digits, then use `mget` to get them into a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$'))
```

Get the common intersecting elements after extracting the 'ID' column

```
ids <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(lst1, `[[`, "ID"))
```

and subset the `list` elements and keep it in a `list`

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, subset, subset = ID %in% ids)
```

-output

```
lst2
#$df1
#     ID  H2
#1 3254D YUB
#3  1089 WER

#$df2
#     ID  Q2
#2  1089 EDR
#3 3254D DFH

#$df3
#     ID  X2
#3  1089 UIO
#4 3254D BHY
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("3254D", "1011A", "1089", "1043"), H2 = c("YUB", 
"WSX", "WER", "RFR")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("1021A", "1089", "3254D", "1043"), Q2 = c("QAZ", 
"EDR", "DFH", "RFV")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df3 <- structure(list(ID = c("1011A", "1569V", "1089", "3254D"), X2 = c("WSX", 
"PKJ", "UIO", "BHY")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Your solution with Reduce() is exactly what I was looking for right now. I was trying to find some solution with map() but I think in this case base R is much better. Thank you.